# CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH isn't using the system path

Tags: cmake, gdal, vcpkg

On Windows 10, I am trying to get GDAL to build with Python bindings with vcpkg manifest mode.  To do this, the GDAL cmake file looks for the swig executable.  The search paths don't match up with the paths in my Path system environment variable, and the list of paths cmake is finding from CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH do not match up with my system Path.  Is there an alternate source for CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH?

The specific error is:

```
  SWIG is a requirement to build the Python bindings
```

Which is caused by this (I have also declared SWIG_EXECUTABLE and SWIG_DIR in my system environment variables just in case.):

```
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/test_vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:855 (_find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:169 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find SWIG (missing: SWIG_EXECUTABLE SWIG_DIR) 
CMake Debug Log at D:/test_vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:855 (_find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for FindSWIG.cmake:

    D:/test_vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/gdal/src/v3.7.1-4bc9b9cce9.clean/cmake/modules/packages/FindSWIG.cmake
    D:/test_vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/gdal/src/v3.7.1-4bc9b9cce9.clean/cmake/modules/thirdparty/FindSWIG.cmake
    D:/test_vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/gdal/src/v3.7.1-4bc9b9cce9.clean/cmake/modules/FindSWIG.cmake
    D:/test_vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/gdal/src/v3.7.1-4bc9b9cce9.clean/cmake/modules/../helpers/FindSWIG.cmake

  The file was found at

    C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindSWIG.cmake

  The module is considered not found due to SWIG_FOUND being FALSE.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:169 (find_package)
```

I am using a slightly modified overlay for vcpkg for gdal if that information is necessary.

Here is the section of config-x64-windows-out.log that seems to show what Cmake is finding on the path:

```
  Standard system environment variables
  [CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE/VC/vcpackages
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Team Tools/Performance Tools/x64
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Team Tools/Performance Tools
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Common/VSPerfCollectionTools/vs2019/x64
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Common/VSPerfCollectionTools/vs2019
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v10.0A/bin/NETFX 4.8 Tools/x64
    C:/Program Files (x86)/HTML Help Workshop
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/FSharp/Tools
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Team Tools/DiagnosticsHub/Collector
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.22621.0/x64
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/x64
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64
    C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/Tools
    D:/test_vcpkg/vcpkg/downloads/tools/powershell-core-7.2.11-windows
    C:/Windows/System32
    C:/Windows
    C:/Windows/System32/wbem
    C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/IDE/VC/Linux/bin/ConnectionManagerExe
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/vcpkg
```

Here is the output of cmake trying to find swig:

```
CMake Debug Log at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindSWIG.cmake:89 (find_program):
  find_program called with the following settings:

    VAR: SWIG_EXECUTABLE
    NAMES: "swig4.0"
           "swig3.0"
           "swig2.0"
           "swig"
    Documentation: Path to a program.
    Framework
      Only Search Frameworks: 0
      Search Frameworks Last: 1
      Search Frameworks First: 0
    AppBundle
      Only Search AppBundle: 0
      Search AppBundle Last: 1
      Search AppBundle First: 0
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_INSTALL_PREFIX: 1

    find_program considered the following locations:

    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/bin/swig4.0.com
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/bin/swig4.0.exe
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/bin/swig4.0
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/sbin/swig4.0.com
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/sbin/swig4.0.exe
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/sbin/swig4.0
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/swig4.0.com
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/swig4.0.exe
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/swig4.0
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/bin/swig4.0.com
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/bin/swig4.0.exe
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/bin/swig4.0
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/sbin/swig4.0.com
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/sbin/swig4.0.exe
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/sbin/swig4.0
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/swig4.0.com
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/swig4.0.exe
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/swig4.0
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/tools/swig4.0.com
    D:/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/debug/vcpkg-installed/x64-windows/tools/swig4.0.exe
    ... Abbreviated for length, suffice to say it isn't searching my Path.
```

Here is a sample of my path, edited for privacy.  swig.exe is sitting on C:\src\swigwin-4.1.1

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;
C:\windows\system32;
C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.1\;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\src\swigwin-4.1.1;
```

I haven't tried much of anything yet since I don't understand how the variable works.  Installing the gdal package by hand isn't an option as I am trying to automate it.

Here is the gdal cmake:

```
# CMake4GDAL project is distributed under MIT license. See accompanying file LICENSE.txt.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9...3.23)

project(gdal LANGUAGES C CXX)
include(CTest)

set(GDAL_LIB_TARGET_NAME GDAL)

#
# setup cmake modules paths
include(cmake/modules/init.cmake)

#
# template files path
set(GDAL_CMAKE_TEMPLATE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/template)
#
# Custom global properties
define_property(
  GLOBAL
  PROPERTY GDAL_FORMATS
  BRIEF_DOCS "Builtin format"
  FULL_DOCS "Builtin format")
define_property(
  GLOBAL
  PROPERTY OGR_FORMATS
  BRIEF_DOCS "Builtin ogr drivers"
  FULL_DOCS "Builtin ogr drivers")
define_property(
  GLOBAL
  PROPERTY PLUGIN_MODULES
  BRIEF_DOCS "Plugin modules"
  FULL_DOCS "Plugin modules")
define_property(
  TARGET
  PROPERTY PLUGIN_OUTPUT_DIR
  BRIEF_DOCS "Plugin modules build directories"
  FULL_DOCS "Plugin modules build directories")
#
# check compiler and set preferences.
if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
endif()

if (NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
    set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
    set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
endif()

#
if (MSVC)
  add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE)
  add_definitions(-DNOMINMAX)
endif ()
#
include(CheckCompilerMachineOption)
include(CheckCompilerSIMDFeature)
include(Ccache)

#
if ("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}" MATCHES "(x86|AMD64)")
  check_compiler_machine_option(flag SSE)
  if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL "")
    set(HAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME 1)
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME)
    if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL " ")
      set(GDAL_SSE_FLAG ${flag})
    endif ()
  endif ()

  check_compiler_machine_option(flag SSE2)
  if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL "")
    set(HAVE_SSE2_AT_COMPILE_TIME 1)
    if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL " ")
      set(GDAL_SSE2_FLAG ${flag})
    endif ()
  endif ()

  check_compiler_machine_option(flag SSSE3)
  if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL "")
    set(HAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME 1)
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME)
    if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL " ")
      set(GDAL_SSSE3_FLAG ${flag})
    endif ()
  endif ()

  check_compiler_machine_option(flag SSE4_1)
  if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL "")
    set(HAVE_SSE41_AT_COMPILE_TIME 1)
    if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL " ")
      set(GDAL_SSE41_FLAG ${flag})
    endif ()
  endif ()

  check_compiler_machine_option(flag AVX)
  if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL "")
    set(HAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME 1)
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME)
    if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL " ")
      set(GDAL_AVX_FLAG ${flag})
    endif ()
  endif ()

  check_compiler_machine_option(flag AVX2)
  if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL "")
    set(HAVE_AVX2_AT_COMPILE_TIME 1)
    if (NOT ${flag} STREQUAL " ")
      set(GDAL_AVX2_FLAG ${flag})
    endif ()
  endif ()

endif ()
#
option(CLANG_TIDY_ENABLED "Run clang-tidy with the compiler." OFF)
set(CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS
    "-*,clang-analyzer-alpha.unix.cstring.*"
    CACHE STRING "clang-tidy checks")
set(CLANG_TIDY_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS
    "clang-analyzer-alpha.unix.cstring.*"
    CACHE STRING "clang-tidy warnings as errors.")
if (RUN_CLANG_TIDY)
  if (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "RUN_CLANG_TIDY requires an out-of-source build!")
  endif ()
  find_program(CLANG_TIDY_COMMAND NAMES clang-tidy)
  if (NOT CLANG_TIDY_COMMAND)
    message(WARNING "RUN_CLANG_TIDY is ON but clang-tidy is not found!")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY)
  else ()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY
        "${CLANG_TIDY_COMMAND}" "-checks='${CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS}'" "-header-filter='${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*'"
        "-warnings-as-errors='${CLANG_TIDY_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS}'")
  endif ()
endif ()

if (APPLE)
  # To avoid the issue mentioned at
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523911/osx-homebrew-cmake-libpng-version-mismatch-issue on github action
  # MacOSX workers that have the Mono framework installed, whose libpng headers will be used instead of the homebrew
  # ones
  get_property(
    result
    CACHE CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK
    PROPERTY TYPE)
  if (NOT result)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK LAST)
    message(STATUS "Setting CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=${CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK}")
  endif ()
endif ()

#
# Developer may want to specify some variable to find proper version.
# ~~~
# Priority is as same order as follows:
#   1. `Python_LOOKUP_VERSION`: specify major.minor version to find.
#   2. 'Python_FIND_VIRTUALENV': specify 'ONLY' to use virtualenv activated.
#   3. `Python_ROOT`: specify installed location.
#   4. If nothing specified, use default behavior.
#
# for example
#   $ cmake -DPython_LOOKUP_VERSION=3.6.0 ..
#   $ cmake -DPython_FIND_VIRTUALENV=ONLY ..
#   $ cmake -DPython_ROOT=C:\Python36 ..
# ~~~
#
include(FeatureSummary)

find_package(SWIG)
set_package_properties(
  SWIG PROPERTIES
  DESCRIPTION
    "Software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages."
  URL "http://swig.org/"
  TYPE RECOMMENDED)

if (Python_LOOKUP_VERSION)
    set(Python_FIND_STRATEGY VERSION)
    find_package(Python ${Python_LOOKUP_VERSION} EXACT COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
else ()
    set(Python_FIND_STRATEGY LOCATION)
    find_package(Python 3.6 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
endif ()
set_package_properties(Python PROPERTIES PURPOSE "SWIG_PYTHON: Python binding")

if (NOT Python_FOUND AND ${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS "3.12.0")
  # On Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6, the backported FindPython package we have in cmake/modules/3.16 doesn't manage to
  # find automatically Python (we can make it work by manually setting -DPython_LOOKUP_VERSION=3.6.9
  # -DPython_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
  # -DPython_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy ) but this is a bit painful. So
  # use the deprecated method (since CMake 3.12), which works out of the box in that situation.
  find_package(PythonInterp)
  find_package(PythonLibs)
  if (PYTHONINTERP_FOUND AND "${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}" VERSION_LESS "3.6")
    set(PYTHONINTERP_FOUND FALSE)
    set(PYTHONLIBS_FOUND FALSE)
  endif()
  if (PYTHONINTERP_FOUND)
    set(Python_Interpreter_FOUND TRUE)
    set(Python_EXECUTABLE ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE})
    set(Python_VERSION_MAJOR ${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR})
    set(Python_VERSION_MINOR ${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR})
  endif ()
  if (PYTHONLIBS_FOUND)
    set(Python_Development_FOUND TRUE)
    set(Python_LIBRARIES ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
    set(Python_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  endif ()
endif ()
if (Python_Interpreter_FOUND)
  file(
    GENERATE
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/python_executable.txt"
    CONTENT "${Python_EXECUTABLE}")
  if(NOT Python_NumPy_FOUND)
    # Detect numpy
    file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/get_numpy.py
         "try:\n  import numpy\n  print(numpy.get_include())\nexcept:\n  pass\n")
    execute_process(
      COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/get_numpy.py
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE _numpy_include
      OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
    if (NOT _numpy_include STREQUAL "")
      set(Python_NumPy_FOUND TRUE)
      set(Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    endif ()
  endif()
endif()

if (SWIG_FOUND AND (Python_Interpreter_FOUND OR Python_FOUND))
  option(BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS "Build Python bindings" ON)
else()
  option(BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS "Build Python bindings" OFF)
endif()

if (BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS)
    if (NOT (Python_Interpreter_FOUND OR Python_FOUND))
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Python is a requirement to build the Python bindings")
    endif()
    if (NOT SWIG_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "SWIG is a requirement to build the Python bindings")
    endif()
endif()

#
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gdal.cmake)

if (BUILD_TESTING AND EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/autotest")
  # unit tests
  add_subdirectory(autotest/cpp)
  if(BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS)
      add_subdirectory(autotest)
  endif()
endif ()
if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fuzzers")
    # Google OSS-Fuzz project utilities
    add_subdirectory(fuzzers)
    if (BUILD_TESTING)
        add_subdirectory(fuzzers/tests)
    endif()
endif()
if (BUILD_TESTING AND EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/perftests")
  add_subdirectory(perftests)
endif ()
# vim: ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 et
```

Comment: What is the higher level requirement to build gdal from source? Almost no one needs to build their own gdal libraries on windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77137660/how-does-one-build-gdal-3-7-2-binaries/77147066

Comment: @robert-davy Thank you for the reference.  The codebase's dependencies are extremely minimal (most of the code only depends on 3 open-source libraries), so there might be some pushback from other devs about introducing conda as a dependency for building the repo.  After talking to other devs, I found other ways around the problem, but I want to leave the question up out of curiosity about the cmake variable.